# Can I use different datatemplate for same datatype basedon some creteria?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I'm new to wpf and now I have a problem. I have a model class say `Customer` and I've created a DataTemplate with `TargetType` property set to `Customer`. It works good. But I actually want two different templates like one for just displaying the record and another for in-place editing. Is it possible to specify two different templates for same datatype based on some creteria? 
And I want to switch this template based on some property on ViewModel like when `IsEditmode` is `True`.

Or am I doing it wrong? Should I use styles instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach seems to be perfectly fine.

You can create a [DataTemplateSelector](http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQhgIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.switchonthecode.com%2Ftutorials%2Fwpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector&ei=P-ZWTbeZAombOq347JAF&usg=AFQjCNG9dl3FAAKkUKACAgwBwa8m-qZlAw&sig2=IERg0CXTJHhbKIClAhvcCQ) which will allow you to choose a data template based on arbitrary criteria from code behind.

I often use these to decide which template to use based on a enum-type property.

Answer (score 2):

There are two easy ways I can think of, ofcourse there are other ways based on the complexity and architecture you want to follow.

1. Define DataTemplate with 'Key' and specifically call that either using StaticResource/DynamicResource Binding.
2. You can have a DataTrigger inside the datatemplate which makes some parts of the template visible/collapsed based on your 'EditMode' property